# Identifier not found? (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I tried compiling a Visual Studio project today, and it gives me "Identifier not Found" errors, I have changed nothing since yesterday, I've tried cleaning, restarting my PC, copying the files to a new project, and they always give me the same errors, as seen in the screenshot below, the editor itself does not detect any errors.

(sorry if this is a noob question)

[image: VS screenshot]

Output log if it's any help:

````
Warning C4244   '=': conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data    Doge Shooter    D:\Programming\Doge Shooter\Doge Shooter\ecs\enemies\fakeDoge\fakeDoge.h    101 
Error   C3861   'Draw': identifier not found    Doge Shooter    D:\Programming\Doge Shooter\Doge Shooter\ecs\SpriteComponent.h  140 
Error   C3861   'loadTexture': identifier not found Doge Shooter    D:\Programming\Doge Shooter\Doge Shooter\ecs\SpriteComponent.h  95  
Error   C3861   'loadTexture': identifier not found Doge Shooter    D:\Programming\Doge Shooter\Doge Shooter\ecs\oldManBugs.h   17  
Error   C3861   'loadTexture': identifier not found Doge Shooter    D:\Programming\Doge Shooter\Doge Shooter\ecs\oldManBugs.h   18  
Error   C3861   'loadTexture': identifier not found Doge Shooter    D:\Programming\Doge Shooter\Doge Shooter\ecs\enemies\fakeDoge\fakeDoge.h    25  
Error   C3861   'loadTexture': identifier not found Doge Shooter    D:\Programming\Doge Shooter\Doge Shooter\ecs\enemies\fakeDoge\fakeDoge.h    26  
Error   C3861   'loadTexture': identifier not found Doge Shooter    D:\Programming\Doge Shooter\Doge Shooter\ecs\enemies\fakeDoge\fakeDoge.h    27  
Error   C3861   'loadTexture': identifier not found Doge Shooter    D:\Programming\Doge Shooter\Doge Shooter\ecs\ColliderComponent.h    41  
Error   C2653   'TextureManager': is not a class or namespace name  Doge Shooter    D:\Programming\Doge Shooter\Doge Shooter\ecs\SpriteComponent.h  95  
Error   C2653   'TextureManager': is not a class or namespace name  Doge Shooter    D:\Programming\Doge Shooter\Doge Shooter\ecs\SpriteComponent.h  140 
Error   C2653   'TextureManager': is not a class or namespace name  Doge Shooter    D:\Programming\Doge Shooter\Doge Shooter\ecs\oldManBugs.h   17  
Error   C2653   'TextureManager': is not a class or namespace name  Doge Shooter    D:\Programming\Doge Shooter\Doge Shooter\ecs\oldManBugs.h   18  
Error   C2653   'TextureManager': is not a class or namespace name  Doge Shooter    D:\Programming\Doge Shooter\Doge Shooter\ecs\enemies\fakeDoge\fakeDoge.h    25  
Error   C2653   'TextureManager': is not a class or namespace name  Doge Shooter    D:\Programming\Doge Shooter\Doge Shooter\ecs\enemies\fakeDoge\fakeDoge.h    26  
Error   C2653   'TextureManager': is not a class or namespace name  Doge Shooter    D:\Programming\Doge Shooter\Doge Shooter\ecs\enemies\fakeDoge\fakeDoge.h    27  
Error   C2653   'TextureManager': is not a class or namespace name  Doge Shooter    D:\Programming\Doge Shooter\Doge Shooter\ecs\ColliderComponent.h    41  ```
````

Comment: These are all compiler errors.  We need a [mre] that includes the code that won't compile.

Comment: Looks like you are missing an include for the header of  your `TextureManager` class.

Comment: Maybe you have a circular include path where 2 or more headers are including each other. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)